# How do I avoid the need to create a temporary file to run two commands from a bash shell?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I need to run two commands. The first creates a file that is used as an input parameter to the second. I can run like this:

```
$ cmd1 p1 p2 > tmp.txt
$ cmd2 -i tmp.txt p3
```

The `-i` parameter on `cmd2` takes a filename. Is there a way I can do this in one line without creating the `tmp.txt` file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try "process substitution" (that's what the Bash manual calls it)

```
cmd2 -i <(cmd1 p1 p2) p3
```

This also works the other way:

```
cmd2 -o >(cmd1 p1 p2) p3
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks Martijn. Is this only a bash feature or do other shells support this sort of thing also?

Comment: I think this syntax might be bash-only. Maybe a shell like zsh supports it as well.

Comment: @stand: This syntax is bash. Other shells might support a similar function though

Answer (score -1):

```
cmd1 p1 p2|xargs cmd2 p3 -i
```

xargs will invoke `cmd2` and turn its own stdin (the output of cmd1) into command line arguments for cmd2.

Comment: The OP wants to avoid creating a temporary file, not use the output of `cmd1` as a filename.